Why does calling my microservice in Java Spring Boot returns 403 Forbidden?
I am using SpringBoot with Eureka Server. I have a users microservice, one eureka server and one springcloud apigateway folder. Here is the complete source code
In my users microservice's controller , I have below code
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UsersController {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    UsersService usersService;

    @GetMapping("/status/check")
    public String status(){
        System.out.println("hereeeeeeeeeee");
        return "Working "+env.getProperty("local.server.port");
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<CreateUserResponseModel> createUser(@Valid @RequestBody CreateUserRequestModel userDetails) {
        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
        modelMapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);
        UserDto userDto = modelMapper.map(userDetails, UserDto.class);
        UserDto createdUser = usersService.createUser(userDto);
        CreateUserResponseModel body = modelMapper.map(createdUser, CreateUserResponseModel.class);
        return  ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(body);
    }
    
}

Now the Get api endpoint returns in 403 Forbidden , the post endpoint works fine
Below is the screenshot of the error

I have defined AuthorizationHeaderFilter class in apigateway which is used for decoding jwt which I am sending in the GET Api Endpoint and it properly decodes the JWT
@Component
public class AuthorizationHeaderFilter extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<AuthorizationHeaderFilter.Config>{

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    public AuthorizationHeaderFilter(){
        super(Config.class);
    }

    public static class Config{

    }

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
        return (exchange,chain)->{
            ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();
            if(!request.getHeaders().containsKey(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION)){
                return onError(exchange,"No authorization header",HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
            }
            String authorizationHeader = request.getHeaders().get(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION).get(0);
            String jwt = authorizationHeader.replace("Bearer ", ""); //Make sure you add space
            if(!isJwtValid(jwt)){
                return onError(exchange, "Jwt token is invalid",HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
            }
            return chain.filter(exchange);
        };
    }

    private Mono<Void> onError(ServerWebExchange exchange,String err,HttpStatus httpStatus){
        ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
        response.setStatusCode(httpStatus);
        return response.setComplete();
    }

    private boolean isJwtValid(String jwt){
        System.out.println("1");
        boolean isValid = false;
        String subject = null;
        String tokenSecret = environment.getProperty("token.secret");
        System.out.println("2 "+tokenSecret);
        SecretKey secretKey = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(tokenSecret.getBytes());

        JwtParser jwtParser = Jwts.parser().verifyWith(secretKey).build();
        try{
            // Jwt<Header,Claims> parsedToken = jwtParser.parse(jwt);
            subject = jwtParser.parseSignedClaims(jwt).getPayload().get("userId").toString();
            System.out.println("3 "+subject);
        } catch(Exception ex){
            isValid = false;
            System.out.println("4 "+ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        if(subject == null || subject.isEmpty()){
            isValid = false;
        } else {
            isValid = true;
        }
        System.out.println("5 ");
        return isValid;
    }

  
}

Here is the application.properties of my apigateway
spring.application.name=api-gateway
server.port=8082
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8010/eureka

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=users-status-check
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=lb://users-ws
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/users-ws/users/status/check
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[1]=Method=GET
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[2]=Header=Authorization, Bearer (.*)
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[0]=RemoveRequestHeader=Cookie
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[1]=RewritePath=/users-ws/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[2]=AuthorizationHeaderFilter

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].id=users-ws
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].uri=lb://users-ws
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].predicates[0]=Path=/users-ws/users
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].predicates[1]=Method=POST
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].filters[0]=RemoveRequestHeader=Cookie
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].filters[1]=RewritePath=/users-ws/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].id=users-ws-h2-console
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].uri=lb://users-ws
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].predicates[0]=Path=/users-ws/h2-console
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].predicates[1]=Method=GET
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].filters[0]=RemoveRequestHeader=Cookie
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].filters[1]=RewritePath=/users-ws/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].id=users-ws-login
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].uri=lb://users-ws
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].predicates[0]=Path=/users-ws/users/login
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].predicates[1]=Method=POST
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].filters[0]=RemoveRequestHeader=Cookie
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].filters[1]=RewritePath=/users-ws/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[4].id=users-ws-get-update-delete
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[4].uri=lb://users-ws
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[4].predicates[0]=Path=/users-ws/users/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[4].predicates[1]=Method=GET,PUT,DELETE
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[4].predicates[2]=Header=Authorization, Bearer (.*)
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[4].filters[0]=RemoveRequestHeader=Cookie
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[4].filters[1]=AuthorizationHeaderFilter
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[4].filters[2]=RewritePath=/users-ws/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}

token.secret=1aBcD3eF4gH5iJ6kL7mN8oP9qRsTuVwXyZ0A1bCdEfG2hI3jK4lM5nO6pQ7rStU8vW9xYz


In your postman screenshot, you set the Authorization manually under the Headers tab. Just for a sanity check, is there anything set under the Authorization tab?

@wxker this is my authorisation tab https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myproject-6952a.appspot.com/o/Screenshot%202024-05-19%20at%209.32.01%E2%80%AFAM.png?alt=media&token=bdb46904-90f5-4df0-a92a-38023fada198

Can you enable the spring security logs in your users microservices by adding to your application.properties (or similar) logging.logger.org.springframework.security=DEBUG. You should see where the 403 is coming from.

@silver_mx logging.logger.org.springframework.security=DEBUG is not a valid property

See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-enable-logging. Yes, I typed the property wrong, sorry.

@silver_mx I get this logs  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /users/status/check
o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /error
o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access

I think in your users service you have some sort of security configuration but your link to the source code does not work. The issue is probably in how spring security is configured. Can you fix the link to see the complete source code?

@silver_mx Can you check this link https://github.com/BraveEvidence/SpringBottMicorServiceTry for source code

I updated the file WebSecurity.java in your users service, and changed the line:
.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/users")
.permitAll()

to
.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.requestMatchers("/users/**")
.permitAll()

So that Spring Security allows not only POST requests but also the GET ones and also you are able to call paths under /users. After that I got a correct response.

In WebSecurity your first requestMatchers only validates the security for /users and /h2-console/** - so your /users/status/checks endpoint will never be authorized by any filter, and will always return 403.
Your POST /users endpoint is always permitted which is why it's working for you.

Add produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE.
@GetMapping(path = "/status/check", produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
public String status()
{
    System.out.println("hereeeeeeeeeee");
    return "Working";
}



does not work same issue. Also the url which you're hitting is wrong. It should be http://localhost:8082/users-ws/users/status/check and it requires a bearer token so you can't hit it from browser as I have added AuthorisationFilter to that endpoint
